# Cannot connect to an SSH server or even ping it, until after scanning the server with `nmap`

Tags: networking, ssh, ping, nmap

I have a Linux server on my local area network. I tried to connect to its known IP address with the following result:

```
scott@CN100819:~$ ssh admin@192.168.99.63
ssh: connect to host 192.168.99.63 port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

So of course I tried to ping the address to verify responsiveness:

```
C:\Users\scottbailey>ping 192.168.99.63
Pinging 192.168.99.180 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

So I assumed the server had somehow lost its connectivity to the network. 
HOWEVER it gets interesting – as a last ditch, I ran `nmap` on the address… and low and behold it was available:

```
C:\Users\scottbailey>nmap 192.168.99.63
Starting Nmap 7.31 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-01-25 12:45 Atlantic Standard Time
Nmap scan report for 192.168.99.63
Host is up (0.0033s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
23/tcp  open  telnet
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
MAC Address: 5C:77:57:00:3D:D2 (Haivision Network Video)
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.50 seconds
```

At that point I was very surprised, so I tried `ssh` again and this time it worked. Can anyone explain why this occurred? Why would `ping` and `ssh` commands not be able to communicate with an address until `nmap` did its magic?

Comment: disable your firewall
https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/809

Comment: @IporSircer if it is my firewall, why does running nmap once suddenly allow me to both ping and connect to it via SSH?

Comment: it caused by a bug which is explained on the link i've written. Sorry, i'm not one of the winbash developers, so i can't tell you it more exactly.